# user_host column from general_log table

Tags: mysql

I enabled the general log for a host to record the transactions. In the user_host column, I see a weird entry as [] @ []. I know that this column should represent host and ip accessed from. what does this [] @ [] mean ?

MariaDB [(none)]> select * from mysql.general_log limit 20;
+----------------------------+------------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------------------------------------+
| event_time                 | user_host                    | thread_id | server_id | command_type | argument                                  |
+----------------------------+------------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------------------------------------+
| 2016-11-03 16:03:46.626159 | [] @  []                     |         8 |      2001 | Query        | BEGIN                                     |
| 2016-11-03 16:03:46.635936 | [] @  []                     |         8 |      2001 | Query        | COMMIT /* implicit, from Xid_log_event */ |
| 2016-11-03 16:03:46.676147 | [] @  []                     |         8 |      2001 | Query        | BEGIN                                     |
| 2016-11-03 16:03:46.676273 | [] @  []                     |         8 |      2001 | Query        | COMMIT /* implicit, from Xid_log_event */ |
| 2016-11-03 16:03:46.780307 | [] @  []                     |         8 |      2001 | Query        | BEGIN                                     |
| 2016-11-03 16:03:46.780388 | [] @  []                     |         8 |      2001 | Query        | COMMIT /* implicit, from Xid_log_event */ |
| 2016-11-03 16:03:46.905406 | [marin] @  [10.93.4.71]      |  51314889 |      2001 | Connect      | marin@10.93.4.71 as anonymous on          |
| 2016-11-03 16:03:46.905440 | marin[marin] @  [10.93.4.71] |  51314889 |      2001 | Query        | SET NAMES utf8                            |
| 2016-11-03 16:03:46.905588 | marin[marin] @  [10.93.4.71] |  51314889 |      2001 | Query        | select @@version_comment limit 1          |
| 2016-11-03 16:03:46.905855 | marin[marin] @  [10.93.4.71] |  51314889 |      2001 | Query        | SHOW PROCESSLIST                          |
| 2016-11-03 16:03:46.906191 | marin[marin] @  [10.93.4.71] |  51314889 |      2001 | Quit         |                                           |
| 2016-11-03 16:03:46.937106 | [] @  []                     |         8 |      2001 | Query        | BEGIN                                     |
| 2016-11-03 16:03:46.937243 | [] @  []                     |         8 |      2001 | Query        | COMMIT /* implicit, from Xid_log_event */ |
| 2016-11-03 16:03:46.988152 | [] @  []                     |         8 |      2001 | Query        | BEGIN                                     |
| 2016-11-03 16:03:46.988237 | [] @  []                     |         8 |      2001 | Query        | COMMIT /* implicit, from Xid_log_event */ |
| 2016-11-03 16:03:47.196839 | [] @  []                     |         8 |      2001 | Query        | BEGIN                                     |
| 2016-11-03 16:03:47.197648 | [] @  []                     |         8 |      2001 | Query        | COMMIT /* implicit, from Xid_log_event */ |
| 2016-11-03 16:03:47.958601 | [marin] @  [10.93.4.71]      |  51314890 |      2001 | Connect      | marin@10.93.4.71 as anonymous on          |
| 2016-11-03 16:03:47.958635 | marin[marin] @  [10.93.4.71] |  51314890 |      2001 | Query        | SET NAMES utf8                            |
| 2016-11-03 16:03:47.958884 | marin[marin] @  [10.93.4.71] |  51314890 |      2001 | Query        | select @@version_comment limit 1          |
+----------------------------+------------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------------------------------------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I THINK You are using master slave In mysql and this process are run by Mysql it self. So no record made for this.

```
 implicit, from Xid_log_event is used in master slave data commit
```

Comment: why you negative this answer